# org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException Error communicating with the remote browser phantom js

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to automate gmail sending a email using selenium i am using phantom js (For headless)

I am getting the following Exception

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException  Error communicating with the remote browser

```
Capabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
         ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);                
         ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
         ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability(
                 PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
                 "C:\\jars\\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe"
             );
        //File file = new File("C:/jars/phantomjs-2.0.0-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");             
       // System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());        
       WebDriver d = new PhantomJSDriver(caps); 

//WebDriver d=new HtmlUnitDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 10);
        d.get("https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html");
        System.out.println("navigated to gmail");
        d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        d.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1576, 798));;

        d.findElement(By.id("gmail-sign-in")).click();
        System.out.println("Clicked on Signin");
        Thread.sleep(9000);


        d.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("chaitanyapujari97@gmail.com");
        System.out.println("Entered Email");

        Thread.sleep(9000);
        d.findElement(By.id("next")).click();


        System.out.println("Clicked next");
        d.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("your pwd");
        System.out.println("Entered password");
        Thread.sleep(9000);
        d.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
        System.out.println("Clicked on signin");
        Thread.sleep(9000);


        d.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div")).click();
        System.out.println("Clicked on Compose email");
        //Thread.sleep(9000);
        Thread.sleep(9000);


        d.findElement(By.name("to")).sendKeys("your email");
        System.out.println("Entered To address");

        Thread.sleep(9000);
        d.findElement(By.name("q")).click();
        d.findElement(By.name("subjectbox")).sendKeys("PHANTOm Js");

        System.out.println("Entered Subject");
        //WebElement webElement=d.findElement(By.name("subjectbox"));

        /*String keysPressed =  Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN);
         WebElement element=d.findElement(By.xpath("html/body"));
         element.sendKeys(keysPressed) ;*/
         Thread.sleep(9000);
         d.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[14]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[2]")).click();
        System.out.println("Clicked On send");
```

i am able to add the recipient email address and subject unable to click on send button.

I am not able to figure it out i am new to Headless Selenium automation please help,

Comment: Could you post the selenium version and other environmental details?

Comment: Sending e-mail. I wonder what technology exists today that is better suited for doing this.

Comment: selenium version 2.45 and phantomjs-2.0.0-windows

Comment: @nginx you've got a notification.

Comment: Google serves different pages depending on user agent string and viewport size. You should print the page source to see if the element exists and whether it way you would identify it changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it the problem was with the jar i was using the jar phantomjsdriver-1.1.0.jar i have changed the versions of jar now which is phantomjsdriver-1.2.1.jar works perfectly fine.

Thanks for the help friends.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this , I hope it will help you , Why are you using such long XPATH , it will have to traverse from html.

```
 d.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[@class='n1tfz']/td[1]/div[1]/div[2]")).click();
```

Comment: no it didnt work out thanks for the help, i m using these xpaths as the id are getting changed.

Comment: Dont use ID , but the tr class is always same. Are you taking screenshot , please try to take screenshot , may be there is some other issue. You can take screenshot by 
((PhantomJSDriver) d).executePhantomJS("var page=this;" +"page.render('./screen/1.png');");

Comment: yes i am taking screen shot to ensure i am on the right screen thanks for the help